# Is the magnitude of a component of a vector always less than its norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\| \cdot\|$ a norm defined on $\mathbb R^n$. Is it true that $|x_i| \leq \| x\|,\forall i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$?
I know this easily proved for $\|\cdot \|_2$ or  $\| \cdot\|_{\infty}$,
and that the statement may be true using the fact that norms are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$ but haven't been able to show how.

Comment: The question as stated is quite easy since for every linear bijection $T:\mathbf{R}^d \to \mathbf{R}^d,$ the function $x \mapsto \| T(x) \|_2$ defines a norm. Then, you can choose $T$ to make the components of $x$ small, so you'd be comparing the norm of a small vector vs one component. What may be interesting though is to see if $| x_i | \| e_i \| \leq \| x \|$ for any vector $x.$ I'd suspect this is also not true (an maybe someone provides a constructor of counterexamples as I did for your question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, it is false. If you define$$\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\|=\frac12\sqrt{x_1^{\,2}+x_2^{\,2}+\cdots+x_n^{\,2}},$$then $\|(1,0,0,\ldots,0)\|=\frac12$, but $1>\frac12$.

Comment: Good example, this raises the question what about defining the magnitude of a component as ||(x_1,0,0..,0)||

Answer (score 5):

Given any norm $\|\cdot\|$ and any $c>0$, the function $\|\cdot\|'$ defined by $\|x\|'=c\|x\|$ is another norm.  So, for any nonzero vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, you can choose a norm to make $\|x\|$ any positive real number at all: just start with some arbitrary norm, and then scale it to make $\|x\|$ have the value that you want.  In particular, if $x_i\neq 0$, you can pick a norm such that $\|x\|$ will be smaller than $|x_i|$.